# Explanation about a result

Tags: java, int, long-integer

Hi i hav a little problem about some code that i can't give an explanation about the result i have.

```
//what happens?
public static void what() {
    int number = 2147483647;
    System.out.println(number + 33);
}

//Here is my solution for the probleme
public static void what() {
    long number = 2147483647;
    System.out.println(number + 33);
}
```

The first code with the int number as variable gives me `-2147483616` as result. So when i change the int to long i get the good result expected. So question is who can help me give and explanation of why int `number + 33 = -2147483616`

Comment: You have exceeded the maximum capacity of the primitive datatype `int`…

Comment: @deHaar, yes i know int is between -2 147 483 648 and 2 147 483 647. Is it sufficient to just say i exceeded the limit?

Comment: You cannot pack a larger number into a variable of type `int`, if you do, you will get an `int` which counts up from the lowest possible value, which is then negative. You can check if a number is greater than the maximum.

Comment: I don't think it is sufficient to only say that the limit is exceeded, because that does not explain the *specific* result we obtain

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java integers are based on 32 Bits. The first bit is kept for the sign (+ = 0 / - = 1).

So `2147483647` equals `01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111`.

Adding more will force the value to turn to negative because the first bit is turned into a 1.

`10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000` equals `-2147483648`.

The remaining 32 you are adding to `-2147483648` brings you to your result of `-2147483616`.

Comment: Thks for the answers and also for the votes. I thing this answer is simple And clear

Answer (score 0):

The primitive int type has a maximum value of 2147483647, which is what you are setting number to. When anything is added to this value the int type cannot represent it correctly and 'wraps' around, becoming a negative number.

The maximum value of the long type is 9223372036854775807 so the second code snippet works fine because long can hold that value with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have reached the maximum of the primitive type int (2147483647).
If int overflows, it goes back to the minimum value (-2147483648) and continues from there.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the calculation of the  second snippet, and what the result actually means.

```
long number = 2147483647;
number += 33;
```

The result in decimal is 2147483680, in hexadecimal (which more easily shows what the value means) it is 0x80000020.

For the first snippet, the result in hexacimal is *also* 0x80000020, because the result of arithmetic with the `int` type is the low 32 bits of the "full" result. What's different is the interpretation: as an `int`, 0x80000020 has the top bit set, and the top bit has a "weight" of -2<sup>31</sup>, so this result is interpreted as -2<sup>31</sup> + 32 (a negative number). As a `long`, the 32nd bit is just a normal bit with a weight of 2<sup>31</sup> and the result is interpreted as 2<sup>31</sup> + 32.

Answer (score 0):

The primitive type `int` is a 32-bit integer that can only store from `-2^31` to `2^31 - 1` whereas `long` is a 64-bit integer so it can obviously store a much larger value.

When we calculate the capacity of `int`, it goes from `-2147483648` to `2147483647`.

Now you are wondering.. why is it that when the number exceeds the limit and I add `33` to it, it will become `-2147483616`?

This is because the data sort of "reset" after exceeding its limit.

Thus, `2147483647 + 1` will lead to `-2147483648`. From here, you can see that `-2147483648 + 32` will lead to the value in your example which is `-2147483616`.

> Some extra info below:

Unless you **really** need to use a number that is greater than the capacity of int, always use int as it takes up less memory space.

Also, should your number be bigger than long, consider using `BigInteger`.

Hope this helps!